# Refactor angular ui-router resolver to use it globally

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have resolve method inside angular config. It was written to protect the view from unauthorized access. Now the problem is, if I create a different route file, I have to copy the same resolve on each file. Is there any other way so that I can write it once and use it everywhere?

```
(function(){

'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');

app.config(/* @ngInject */ function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    var authenticated = ['$q', 'MeHelper', '$state', function ($q, MeHelper, $state) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        MeHelper.ready()
            .then(function (me) {
                if (me.isAuthenticated()) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                } else {
                    deferred.reject();
                    $state.go('login');
                }
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }];

    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: "",
            views: {
                "FullContentView": { templateUrl: "start.html" }
            }
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
             url: "/dashboard",
             views: {
                 "FullContentView": { templateUrl: "dashboard/dashboard.html" }
             },
             resolve: {
                 authenticated: authenticated
             }
         })
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');

     });

})();
```

Edit: `MeHelper` is a Service.

Comment: Could you create something like an `authenticationProvider` and put it in there?

Comment: @plong0 I tried to create authenticationProvider, but couldn't manage to make it work. The injection of MeHelper and $state didn't work on Provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To refactor your code, you should **register a service and take the authentication code to the service**.

**Authenticate service:**

```
app.factory('authenticateService', ['$q', 'MeHelper',
    function($q,MeHelper){

        var obj = {};

        obj.check_authentication = function(params)
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            MeHelper.ready()
                .then(function (me) {
                    if (me.isAuthenticated()) {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject();
                        $state.go('login');
                    }
                });
            return deferred.promise;

        }


        return obj;
    }
]);
```

Then, use this service in any route file in resolve, taking this service name in dependency injection or the function parameter,

**Route configuration file:**

```
(function(){

'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');

app.config(/* @ngInject */ function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


   $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: "",
            views: {
                "FullContentView": { templateUrl: "start.html" }
            }
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
             url: "/dashboard",
             views: {
                 "FullContentView": { templateUrl: "dashboard/dashboard.html" }
             },
             resolve: {
                 authenticated: 
                        function(authenticateService) {
                                return authenticateService.check_authentication();
                        }
             }
         })
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');

     });


})();
```

watch the below lines, this is what we changes in the route configuration to resolve.

the service is injected in below lines:

```
resolve: {
             authenticated: 
                function(authenticateService) {
                             return authenticateService.check_authentication();
                   }
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  How can I inject the service?  Is it possible to just write 

resolve: {
  authenticated: authenticateService.check_authentication();
}

Comment: just try my code, the `authenticateService` given in the function parameter directly injects the authenticateService for you.

Comment: just want to note you can use DI-sytax on ui-router resolve functions: `resolve: {
             authenticated: 
                ['authenticateService', function(authenticateService) {...}] 
}`

Comment: okay, but that may become a bit lengthy syntax, the one which I have taken is simple.

Answer (score 0):

Do your check on route change.

```js
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
        if (unauthorized && $state.current.name !== 'login') {
          $state.go('login');
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Due to the service call ( `MeHelper` is a service ), I couldn't make it work on $rootScope.

Comment: You do not want to be calling the server every time you change route to check if it is authenticated. After login your should store that you are authenticated and just check that.